# Why I can't upgrade Xamarin.forms to higher version in visual studio with Nuget Package manage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I found there are a lot of new version of Xamarin.Form, currently up to 5.0.0.2515.
But I found I can't upgrade Xamarin.forms to higher version in visual studio with Nuget Package manage, highest is 5.0.0.2012.

[image: here]

Anyone knows what is the reason?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using. I use the latest of 2022 version and there is another icon before Xamarin.Forms . And yes there is a higher version

Comment: VS / Solution Explorer / "Manage nuget packages for solution" / Installed / Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

- First, you can update the Visual Studio version you use.
- Second, you can check the Xamarin.Forms Nuget package. You can see the
  Auther is Microsoft and other information about the package.
- Third, here is latest version of the Xamarin.forms. You can refer to the link [Xamarin.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/5.0.0.2545?_src=template)